# htaccess: Ignore Case in RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite these two URLs

```
domain.com/test
domain.com/TEST
```

to this

```
domain.com/test.php
```

This is my current .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(test|TEST)($|/$) /test.php
```

This works for the `/test` URL, but not for `/TEST`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `/TEST` a real directory?

Comment: No, it doesn't exist.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and are there more rules?

Comment: It's in a subdirectory, and the above is all it contains. There are other .htaccess in parent directories - all those contain is `CheckSpelling OFF`, `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php` and `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php`. Thanks for helping me out anubhavan :)

Comment: Change options line to `Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes -MultiViews`

Comment: I tried that before as well - it still doesn't work... weird, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, next option is to enable `RewriteLog` and examine that.

Answer (score 4):

Use of the `[NC]` flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

You have to add [NC] as suffix in rewriteurl

Comment: Thanks for your answer prashant - I just tried that, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Prashant Thakre comment about the [NC] flag is correct. The code below looks for /test while ignoring case and sets the permanent redirect flag.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /test [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/test.php [R=301,L]
```

Here is another option for permanent redirection but it is case sensitive so multiple lines of code are used to match lower and upper case.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /test http://example.com/test.php
Redirect 301 /TEST http://example.com/test.php
```

You can find more information about mod_rewrite options at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Remember to always clear your browser cache when testing mod rewrites. When browsers cache pages, rewrites are usually ignored even if the rewrite works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is posibble do the same for all the pages and with capital and lower letters?

For example contact.html, services.html, prices.html. when you have the rewrite rules to remove .html extension, and when you write , for example, mydomain.com/contact.html or mydomain.com/contact both cases shows mydomain.com/contact and loads contact.html, but, what can you do to make it works when you write mydomain.com/ConTaCt.html or mydomain.com/COntaCT, and other possbilities for all the  pages? Services, prices and all the others, working with or without caps or lower